# Changing limit of vertical scroll area on touchpad 22.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

The default area which is dedicated to the vertical scroll function on my Lenovo G580 touchpad is far too large (approx. 50% of the whole touchpad). I have a workaround whereby every time I boot up the first thing I do is run "**synclient RightEdge=2600**" in a terminal window, but my question is where does the variable **RightEdge** live as it would be nice to change the default value, which when I run "**synclient -l**" is set at **1540**.

So how do I permanently change the **RightEdge** value from **1540** to **2600**?

---

I did check other threads related to this that I could find:
[How to adjust TouchPad edge scroll area in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22101/how-to-adjust-touchpad-edge-scroll-area-in-ubuntu)
and
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=886449
but no matter how I tried to configure the files in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ it has made no difference, so either the contents of my synaptics.conf file aren't being read or the edits I've made have been added to that file incorrectly.

Here's the contents of my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ directories:

[image: Here's the contents of my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ directories]

[image]

---

And the contents of my synaptics.conf file:

[image]

[image]

The section I added is the very last section "InputDevice"